# What does it actually mean to "break bad"?

Tags: breaking-bad, title

What does "breaking bad" actually mean, and in which context has the creator used the term for the title of the TV series [*Breaking Bad* (2008-2013)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0903747/).

Comment: Downvoters - apart from the fact the answer is probably Googleable [which is true for 90% of SE questions & in itself should not be reason to downvote], I see no reason to not ask about a little-known phrase from a small region of what to most people is a foreign country.

Comment: It has to show research effort, and grammar is very important. This doesn't show any research effort, nor does it show an initial push as to their own thoughts behind the meaning.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174891/what-is-the-origin-of-breaking-bad

Comment: It isn't merely googlable, it's explained in the opening paragraph of the Breaking Bad wiki page.

Comment: @Tetsujin - This was obviously a "self-answered question" (the OP answered his own question within a minute of posting, but has since deleted it), and those are pretty hard to pull off successfully.  I didn't downvote, I usually reserve those for blatantly wrong answers or really poor questions, but this one is borderline to my metrics.

Comment: Ah, OK - I don't have the rep on here to see deleted answers yet, so didn't spot that one. My main point was really that I'd watched all 8 seasons before I actually got round to googling what it's supposed to mean, because I'd never heard the phrase before, & that being googleable doesn't make a question 'bad' per se.

Comment: Panther does a good job of aggregating info about the phrase, and it has the benefit of being concise and in one place, so I believe there is some value to having the question here on Stack.

Comment: @Tetsujin I downvoted not because this is a well-known or easily Googleable phrase (I'd never heard it except in the context of this show), but because it's literally explained in the pilot episode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Breaking bad is a slang phrase meaning *to defy authority* or *to challenge conventions*.

[Source Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Break%20Bad)

I have just started watching initial 4-5 episodes and story starts with protagonist starting to work illegally.

Its basically about chemistry teacher who is very simple guy but he is came to know that he has cancer. He is only support for his family and he also have one son who is young and differently able.

So, this fellow comes across one of his old student and starts creating Meth.

You can say its his story of defing authority or law, in other words, Watler is breaking bad.

> Lead actor Bryan Cranston stated in an interview that: "The term 'breaking bad' is a southern colloquialism and it means when someone who has taken a turn off the path of the straight and narrow, when they've gone wrong. And that could be for that day or for a lifetime."
>
> <sub>[Source: http://breakingbad.wikia.com/wiki/Breaking_Bad]</sub>

Showcreaters intially thought that this is very common term as mentioned in [this article](http://entertainment.time.com/2013/09/23/breaking-bad-what-does-that-phrase-actually-mean/):-

> Show creator Vince Gilligan has said that he had thought it was a commonly used phrase when he decided to use it as a title, not knowing that the expression was a Southern regionalism from the area in Virginia from which he hails. It means “to raise hell,” he says, as in “I was out the other night at the bar…and I really broke bad.”